# One-liner return for if else

Tags: python

An invalid syntax error has occurred. I'm just curious to know how to do this as a one-liner.

```
for red, blue in zip(redShirtHeights, blueShirtHeights):
    return False if (shortest == "RED" and red >= blue) else False if (blue > red)
return True
```

if Shortest equals Red so we only need to check if red > blue and not blue > red.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since you don't want to return if blue < red, you can't really do this.

Comment: @TomKarzes That wouldn't work, because the code could return True before the loop iteration has completed, and a later iteration may return False.

Comment: @9769953 Thanks! fixed, but still doesn't work.

Comment: That wasn't my point though.

Comment: You can't use an unconditional `return` statement inside the loop.  You instead need to place the `return` inside an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code causes syntax error. A `return` function must have a return value, but yours in the if-clause might not return anything.

Here's the one-liner.

```
 return not any((shortest == "RED" and red >= blue) or blue > red for red, blue in zip(redShirtHeights, blueShirtHeights))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a one-liner return statement would work, since the `return True` condition requires the entire loop to be evaluated: you can't shortcut the return and put it in the if-else ternary expression.

Here is the simple alternative:

```
for red, blue in zip(redShirtHeights, blueShirtHeights):
    if (shortest == "RED" and red >= blue) or blue > red:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: if Shortest equals Red so we only need to check if red > blue without blue > red. Thanks so much, appreciate the help!

Comment: You just need `if blue > red or shortest == "RED"` (or the reversed order).

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me, thanks to Oplxy.

```
return not any((shortest == "RED" and red >= blue) or (shortest != "RED" and blue >= red) for red, blue in zip(redShirtHeights, blueShirtHeights))
```